# TSQL - Move any text after CR/LF to a new column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have an address field in our database that I need to split up into two columns (Address1 and Address2). I'm looking for a way to split up this string after the CR/LF section.

How can I do this? I'm using SSMS 2016

Comment: You would need to use CHARINDEX or PATINDEX to get both the first part and again with a slight change to get the second part. Hopefully you are doing this so you can fix the data and not just query it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is how the system is designed and I cannot change it

Comment: I feel your pain. Can you add computed columns to the table? I am thinking then at least you could split this into the correct columns and not have to do it repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could be used -

Carriage return is char(13)

```
DECLARE @Str table (str VARCHAR(100))
insert into @Str values
('Test
Word'),
('NoCRLF')

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), Str ) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Str , 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), Str ) - 1) ELSE Str END AS [First],
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), Str ) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Str , CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), Str ) + 1, LEN(Str )) ELSE NULL END AS [Last] 
FROM @Str
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. If there isn't any CR/LF will that affect anything? Not all addresses will have this

Comment: What happens if the are more than one CR/LF in the string?

Comment: In that case would need to check first if the column has any `CR/LF` then do the split. Updated based on the requirement.

Comment: @MarkKram - based on requirement - two columns (Address1 and Address2). Obviously query will change based on changing requirement :)

Comment: This worked out great. I had to change CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)) on the second case statement to CHARINDEX(CHAR(10)) in order for this to work for my instance. Appreciate the help on this. Couldn't figure out why my exports to CSV were getting screwy.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `CHARINDEX` to find if your address has new line character or not. and based on that you can split up you address using `SUBSTRING`.
- For address1, you should start from position 1 and end at position 1 less than index of new line character.
- Similarly for address2, you should start from position 1 more than index of new line character and end the end of the string.
- Code below handles cases like when there is no `CHAR(13)` you will get Address1 only and Address2 will be `NULL`. Same way if Address is `NULL` or Blank space it will handle it.

**Below is the sample code:**

```
    DECLARE @AddressTable AS TABLE
    (
        Address nvarchar(MAX) NULL,
        Address1 nvarchar(MAX) NULL,
        Address2 nvarchar(MAX) NULL
    )

    INSERT @AddressTable (Address)
    SELECT '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue' + CHAR(13) + 'Washington DC ' Address UNION ALL
    SELECT '221 B Baker St, London, England' Address UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL Address UNION ALL
    SELECT '' Address UNION ALL
    SELECT '11 Wall Street' + CHAR(13) + 'New York, NY' Address


    SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), Address) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Address, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), Address) - 1) + '|' 
        ELSE Address END
    Address1,
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), Address) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Address, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), Address) + 1, LEN(Address)) + '|' 
        ELSE NULL END
    Address2
    FROM @AddressTable
```

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2016 there is a string_split function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql